# Why does an event handler never get called if it's added within a loop on an ienumerable?

Tags: .net, ienumerable

Why does an event handler never get called if it's added within a loop on an ienumerable?

For instance:

```
IEnumerable<MyType> list = someCollection.Select(i => new MyType(i));

foreach (var item in list)
item.PropertyChanged += item_PropertyChanged; <-- this never gets called
```

Bu if list is assigned like

```
list = someCollection.Select(i => new MyType(i)).ToArray();
```

the event handler does get called..

Why? (I imagine it has something to do with the fact that a [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) query is lazy, but the fact of looping through the result isn't enough?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Select` call is creating new instances of `MyType`, which means that...

When `list` is typed as `IEnumerable<MyType>` then you're dealing with *a new sequence* of *new* objects each time you enumerate `list`. The objects to which you're adding event handlers *are not* the same objects that you're subsequently testing.

When `list` is typed as `MyType[]` (by using the `ToArray` call) then you're dealing with *the same collection* of objects each time you enumerate `list`. The objects to which you're adding event handlers *are* the same objects that you're subsequently testing.